# Run Ruby thread for Slack bot on only one Unicorn worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn, slack

I created a slack bot and run it like so in a rails initializer:

```
Thread.abort_on_exception = true

Thread.new do
  CorgiBot.run
end
```

I run Unicorn with multiple workers though, so each worker runs the Slack bot. What happens then is that each worker has the same slack bot running on it and so returns multiple responses/messages inside of slack for each command it receives.

I'm trying to avoid running the slack bot on its own server for various reasons. Any ideas for solutions to this using Unicorn or just changing my setup in on Ruby or Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running multiple Unicorn workers means you're running multiple distinct processes - you're basically running multiple copies of the bot.

The easy solution is to just not run it in your Unicorn process, but in a separate standalone process. Rails providers the `runner` command to run scripts in your Rails app environment:

```
rails r 'CorgiBot.run'
```

If that won't work, then you need to take a shared lock somewhere, and the first process to acquire it wins, the other fail. You could do this with a file lock, or by using something like Redis' SETNX command.